# Clicking on button to redirect to another html page

Tags: html, css, visual-studio

I have tried many diff ways like using forms or script but i still cannot get it. this are my current codes. Thank you

```
<button name="nextpg" onclick="redirect()" class="mb-3 signup-btn" >Reset my password</button>

 <script type="text/javascript">
function redirect()
{
var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/cfmemail.html";
window.location(url);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this. It might do the trick for you

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.location.href = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/cfmemail.html';" value="Redirect"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="redirect()">Redirect</button>

<script>
function redirect() {
  location.replace("http://127.0.0.1:8080/cfmemail.html")
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: doesnt seem to work i just geta ? beside the original link